# How to reference and save to buffer

Tags: javascript, sharp

I'm making a program which layers a queue of images onto a background, and I'm not sure how to save to or read from a buffer, and I haven't been able to find example code to reference from.

Because the array of items to composite could be over 100 long, I don't want to use disk access as it will slow the piece down. Any suggestgions

```js
arr = [["./filepath1",xcoord1,ycoord1],[...],[...],[...],...]    
sharp('./../../src_imgs/background.png')
    .composite([{ input: arr[0][0], left: arr[0][1] , top: arr[0][2]}])
    .withMetadata()
    .toFile("./in_progress_imgs/current_iteration.png")
for  (let i = 0; i > filloutFVal.length(); i++) {
    sharp('./in_progress_imgs/current_iteration.png')
        .composite([{ input: arr[j][0], left: arr[j][1] , top: arr[j][2]}])
        .withMetadata()
        .toFile("./in_progress_imgs/current_iteration.png")
};
```

Comment: do `let image = sharp(...)` outside the loop then just do `image = image.composite(...)` in the loop, you don't need to save each time, do the `image.toFile(...)` after the for loop

Comment: by let image = sharp(...), what would I put in the brackets?

Comment: './../../src_imgs/background.png'